# apache2 and couchdb enable cors on apache2

Tags: apache, cors, couchdb

Hy I want to use couchdb from a apache webserver, to use this I have to make cors requests to the couchdb server.
So what I did was creating a new VirtualHost config for apache that look like this(localhost.maxbit89.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias localhost.maxbit89
    ServerName localhost.maxbit89

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost.maxbit89
    <Directory /var/www/localhost.maxbit89/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None

        # Always set these headers.
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
        Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

        # Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But any request I tryed has non of the spezified headers.
So can any body tell me how i use couchdb + apache the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first problem was some how my apache2 config was broken after reinstalling apache the headers were send.

I had a second problem that was solved by adding this to /etc/couchdb/local.ini:

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
```