# Calling php file on another server and display resullt using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

**EDIT**

I set the header of my php file like so:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

And that's the error i get right now in my browser:

*"Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."*

And that's my php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require 'db_handler.php';


$criterion_name = $_GET['name'];

$query = $fm->newFindCommand("DOKUMENTY_PHP");
$query->addFindCriterion('Nazwa', "=*" . $criterion_name . "*");
$query->addFindCriterion('Format_dokumentu', "=" . "PDF");
$query->addFindCriterion('web', "=" . "1");
$result = $query->execute();

if(FileMaker::isError($result)){
    echo($result->getMessage());
    return;
}
$i = 0;
// Get array of found records
$records = $result->getRecords();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    echo '<li> <a href="./plik.php/?filename=' . $record->getField('Nazwa') 
. '.pdf">' . $record->getField('Nazwa') . '</a></li>';
    $i++;
}
echo $i . " Pozycje";

?>
```

---

I am trying to send form from my website to php file on a remote server, send back the result and display it, without reloading page. Everything works fine as long as both website and php file are on the same machine, when separated it stops working.
I figured that the problem probably lies in how i call the php file, but i don't know how to do it any other way.

The file_get_contents() function works without a problem. But i don't think i can use that here.

Here's my html code:

```
<form id="my_form" align = "center">
Nazwa pliku: <input name="name" id="firstname" type="text" />
<input id="submit_form" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<div  id="update_div" onKeyPress="return checkSubmit(event)"></div>

<script>
var submit_button = $('#submit_form');

submit_button.click(function() {
var var_name = $('#firstname').val();
var update_div = $('#update_div');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/show_documents.php',
    data: {name: var_name}, 
    success: function(response){
       update_div.html(response);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/ The problem is more on the server than the client side here.

Comment: This question probably contains your answer if you are using Apache2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536004/apache2-and-couchdb-enable-cors-on-apache2. As CORS is a topic of server client interaction you should add details about your webserver.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So i need to change how my servers communicate with each other. But it seems to complicated form me. Is there any easy CORS tutorial for beginners, or some other easier way to do that?

Comment: Did you read the PHP page from the site which sirko provided? https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html - one line of code is the minimum to get started. You may need a bit more depending on your exact circumstances, but equally that might be sufficient. Is it really so complicated? If you want more in depth / generic discussion of CORS then read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I placed the header in my php file. Didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Please enable in php.ini

```
 allow_url_fopen=On
```

To access from another server using api or ajax.

Comment: That is not the case here because i have it open.

Comment: this setting is a server-side PHP setting and has nothing whatsoever to do with AJAX or CORS. It will affect the ways a PHP script is allowed to make a request to another server (where the PHP script is the _client_) but has no effect on requests which the PHP script is receiving (i.e. acting as the _server_).